# Customized method for dataframe in my analysis module

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, modules

Please download the file and save in home directory and extract it:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/swtw8bk35zr1i6d/analyse.7z?dl=0

I can get some warrants info.

```
import analyse
df = analyse.warrants.get('0788')
```

Now we got `0788`'s warrants info. It output df with better format:

```
analyse.tabulate.tabulate(df)
```

I want to simply the expression as `df.tabulate()`. How do I refactor the code in `analyse` directory?

Show content in tabulate.py:

```
import pandas as pd
from terminaltables import AsciiTable   

def tabulate(df):
    rows = len(df)
    head = [df.columns.tolist()]
    nr = df.values.tolist()
    content = head + nr
    table = AsciiTable(content)
    data_str = table.table.split('\n')
    sep_line = data_str[0]
    transformed_str = []
    for ind in range(0,len(data_str)-1):
        if ind < 3 :
            transformed_str.append(data_str[ind])
        else:
            transformed_str.append(data_str[ind])
            transformed_str.append(sep_line)
    new_str = "\n".join(transformed_str) + '\n' + '\n'  + '[ {} records ]'.format(rows-1)
    print(new_str)
```

I want to refactor `analyse.tabulate.tabulate(df)` as `df.tabulate()`. It is the simplest way to use `df.tabulate()` to get well-formatted dataframe.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're asking. You want to simplify your `tabulate` method?

Comment: I want to refactor `analyse.tabulate.tabulate(df)` as `df.tabulate()`. It is simple to use `df.tabulate()` to get well-formatted dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

This if statement

```
    if ind < 3 :
        transformed_str.append(data_str[ind])
    else:
        transformed_str.append(data_str[ind])
        transformed_str.append(sep_line)
```

Can be rewritten as

```
    transformed_str.append(data_str[ind])
    if ind >= 3:
        transformed_str.append(sep_line)
```

Comment: Not to simplify   tabulate method ,the citation way `analyse.tabulate.tabulate(df)` is too long to write,i want to get same result with `df.tabulate()`.